# Bash script interpreting line continuation as a new command

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to create a configuration script that runs a multiline cmake command.

```
cmake -S . -B build-mac \
    -G Xcode \
    -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES="Debug;Release" \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install/mac \
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=Modules/Darwin.cmake
```

But I get the error

```
" does not exist.source directory "/Users/.../scripts/
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
./release-mac.bash: line 2: -G: command not found
: command not found line 3: -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=Debug;Release
: No such file or directory -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install/mac
: No such file or directory -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=Modules/Darwin.cmake
```

So the all lines following the initial line are being interpreted as new commands. Why is my line continuation not working?

Comment: Does your script have Windows-style CRLF line endings?

Comment: I questioned that myself and then saw this. I think you're exactly right.

Comment: If not the Windows-style line endings, is there any whitespace after the \?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had Windows-style line endings in my script.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569997/how-to-find-out-line-endings-in-a-text-file) suggested useful troubleshooting commands I used:

```
file <file>
cat -v <file>
od -t c <file>
```